# Combobox Font changed

Tags: c#, fonts, combobox, selectedindex

I have a method which is called on selected index changed from a combobox. At this event, i try to change the font of every combox on my form, but sometimes i got an access violation and i don't know what i have todo.
Here is the code:

```
Font font_label = new Font(current_theme["Font_Combo_box"], Convert.ToInt32(current_theme["Font_Size_Combo_box"]), FontStyle.Regular);
        switch (Convert.ToInt32(this.cb_combobox_style.SelectedIndex))
        {
            case 0:
                font_label = new Font(this.cb_combobox_fonts.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(this.cb_combobox_size.SelectedItem.ToString()), FontStyle.Regular);
                break;
            case 1:
                font_label = new Font(this.cb_combobox_fonts.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(this.cb_combobox_size.SelectedItem.ToString()), FontStyle.Bold);
                break;
            case 2:
                font_label = new Font(this.cb_combobox_fonts.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(this.cb_combobox_size.SelectedItem.ToString()), FontStyle.Italic);
                break;
            case 3:
                font_label = new Font(this.cb_combobox_fonts.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(this.cb_combobox_size.SelectedItem.ToString()), FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Bold);
                break;
        }

        this.cb_backgroundimage_layout.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_header_font_size.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_header_fonts.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_header_style.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_label_fonts.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_label_size.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_label_style.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_textbox_font_size.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_textbox_fonts.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_textbox_style.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_themes.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_backgroundimage_show.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_combobox_fonts.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_combobox_size.Font = font_label;
        this.cb_combobox_style.Font = font_label;
```

Comment: Your question lacks details, for instance: Is there any specific error message or is it just the standard _"...tried to read or write protected memory..."_? Also, where does the error occur?

Comment: _"i got an access violation"_ as?

Comment: the error occurs sometimes when i changed the selected font on the combox and than try to change every comboboxes font.